# Can I ask about the underage driving license program in my state?

Tags: discussion, scope, legal-advice

I'd like to ask a question about my state's driving license program, specifically an (apparent) edge case that isn't covered very well by the DMV's website.

Reading [/help/on-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it could go either way - this feels like it could be "legal process and procedure", but it could also fall under "legal advice on a specific matter" (I want to know if I can do something).

This is the gist of what I want to ask:

> I'm almost 17 in (my state). I don't have a burning desire to drive, but it would be nice for a few reasons. Driving with my parents is fine.
>
> Given this, I'd like to stay under a 'supervised instruction permit' (SIP), the "you can drive, but only with a licensed adult" version of a license. I also don't really want to go through driver's training and all that red tape.
>
> It seems I could walk into the DMV, take the test, and get my 'real' license when I turn 17. For insurance purposes, it would be better for me to have an SIP.
>
> **Can I get an SIP when I turn 17 without going through driver's training?** For how long would it be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many legal terms, *legal advice* has a pretty specific meaning that isn't really the ordinary meaning. Provided that you provide the jurisdiction, it's really a matter of lookup up the applicable legislation and providing the information.

Personally, I would not vote to close.

Comment: I agree, and simply feel compelled to comment (since this *just* came up elsewhere) that it's not all that clear what legal advice *is*. Meaning, we need something to click.